# Grafana no graphs displayed

Tags: sql, mariadb, grafana

with Grafana I try to build a dashboard to display used hours per month. The data is stored in mariadb.
My plan is to sum the spent minutes, which is stored in the DB as ***int*** and display it as hours for each month. The field date is stored as ***date*** but in the format: YYYY-MM-DD

My problem now is that no graphs are shown, when the query is stated as below.
BUT: When I have `` (SUM(`minutes`))/60 `` it works, but the result is hours as a decimal and not like ***04:39:01***

As I'm new to this maybe I did something wrong.
Can you please help me?

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'),
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`minutes`)*60)
FROM `nightfury`
WHERE
LEFT(`date`,4) = '2023'
GROUP BY
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m');
```

And the query inspector gives me this output:

```
Object
traceId:undefined
request:Object
url:"api/ds/query?ds_type=mysql&requestId=Q393"
method:"POST"
data:Object
queries:Array[1]
0:Object
refId:"A"
datasource:Object
type:"mysql"
uid:"dd395e0b-8936-4c14-bd5b-3f48cc27f4ea"
rawSql:"SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'),
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`minutes`)*60)
FROM `nightfury`
WHERE
LEFT(`date`,4) = '2023'
GROUP BY
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m');"
format:"table"
datasourceId:2
intervalMs:31536000000
maxDataPoints:1488
queryCachingTTL:undefined
from:"NaN"
to:"NaN"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
results:Object
A:Object
status:200
frames:Array[1]
0:Object
schema:Object
refId:"A"
meta:Object
typeVersion:Array[0,0]
executedQueryString:"-- Fahrzeit
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'),
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`minutes`)*60)
FROM `nightfury`
WHERE
LEFT(`date`,4) = '2023'
GROUP BY
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m');"
fields:Array[2]
0:Object
name:"DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')"
type:"string"
typeInfo:Object
frame:"string"
nullable:true
1:Object
name:"SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`minutes`)*60)"
type:"string"
typeInfo:Object
frame:"string"
nullable:true
data:Object
values:Array[2]
0:Array[11]
0:"2023-01"
1:"2023-02"
2:"2023-03"
3:"2023-04"
4:"2023-05"
5:"2023-06"
6:"2023-07"
7:"2023-08"
8:"2023-09"
9:"2023-10"
10:"2023-11"
1:Array[11]
0:"17:38:00"
1:"19:11:00"
2:"23:28:00"
3:"42:12:00"
4:"24:23:00"
5:"29:37:00"
6:"38:30:00"
7:"33:40:00"
8:"40:52:00"
9:"13:14:00"
10:"04:39:00"
refId:"A"
```